# The differences between tf.nest.map_structure vs tf.map_fn in speed and in results

Tags: python, tensorflow

My question may be summarized as follows:

1. **Why does `tf.map_fn` generate slightly different results compared to `tf.nest.map_structure`?**
2. **Why is `tf.map_fn` much slower than `tf.nest.map_structure`?**
3. **To apply a specific function to each example of a large batch, which one is a more preferred way?**

Now, let me explain the problem that I had in more detail.

I need to apply a certain function to each example in a batch. At first, I tried the `tf.map_fn` method described in:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn.

After implementing using `tf.map_fn`, I realize that the code is terribly slow.
I did some search, and it seems that many people have experienced similar issues.
(e.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24774)

When I replaced `tf.map_fn` with `tf.nest.map_structure`, the speed was much better. However, the results were slightly different.

I made the following toy example to check this case.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf

def func(x):
    return tf.math.sqrt(x) 

x = tf.reshape(tf.range(24, dtype=tf.float32), (4, 6)) 

y1 = tf.nest.map_structure(func, x) 
print (y1)

y2 = tf.map_fn(func, x)
print (y2)

y3 = tf.math.sqrt(x)
print (y3)

print (tf.math.reduce_all(tf.equal(y1, y2)))
print (tf.math.reduce_all(tf.equal(y1, y3)))
```

y1 and y3 are exactly the same but y2 and y3 are slightly different. y2 and y3 are not totally different, but still similar.

The following is the result:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.         0.99999994 1.4142134  1.7320508  1.9999999  2.236068  ]
 [2.4494896  2.6457512  2.8284268  2.9999998  3.1622777  3.3166249 ]
 [3.4641016  3.6055508  3.7416573  3.8729832  3.9999998  4.1231055 ]
 [4.2426405  4.3588986  4.472136   4.5825753  4.6904154  4.7958307 ]], shape=(4, 6), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.        1.        1.4142135 1.7320508 2.        2.236068 ]
 [2.4494898 2.6457512 2.828427  3.        3.1622777 3.3166249]
 [3.4641016 3.6055512 3.7416575 3.8729835 4.        4.1231055]
 [4.2426405 4.358899  4.472136  4.582576  4.690416  4.7958317]], shape=(4, 6), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.         0.99999994 1.4142134  1.7320508  1.9999999  2.236068  ]
 [2.4494896  2.6457512  2.8284268  2.9999998  3.1622777  3.3166249 ]
 [3.4641016  3.6055508  3.7416573  3.8729832  3.9999998  4.1231055 ]
 [4.2426405  4.3588986  4.472136   4.5825753  4.6904154  4.7958307 ]], shape=(4, 6), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)
tf.Tensor(True, shape=(), dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by these two functions as well and wish there are better documentations. But one difference I do notice is that `tf.nest.structure(func, *structure)` applies `func` on each structure of `structure`, while `tf.map_fn(func, elems)` first unpack `elems` on dimension `0` and then applies `func` on the resulted sequence.

Consider the following example:

```
example = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([-1, 1, -1])]


result_1 = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x[0] * x[1], example, dtype=tf.int64)
print(f"{result_1=}")

result_2 = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x: x[0] * x[1], example)
print(f"{result_2=}")
```

Output:

```
result_1=<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([-1,  2, -3])>
result_2=[2, -1]
```

Back to your original question, I couldn't answer 1 and 2 either. As for 3, the two cases I can think of are:

1. If your input is a `tf.Tensor` whose first dimension is batch size then use  `map_fn`
2. If your input is a list whose length is batch size then use `map_structure`.

Again it'd be great if someone could clarify my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

### `tf.map_fn(func, elems)`:

Maps over axis 0. For example:

```py
tf.map_fn(lambda x: x*2, tf.constant([1, 2, 3])) # => [2, 4, 6]
tf.map_fn(lambda x: x[0]*x[1], tf.constant([[1, 0], [2, 4], [3, 5]])) # => [0, 8, 15]
```

### `tf.nest.map_structure(func, *structure)`

#### When `len(structure)==1`

Conceptually:

```py
tf.map_fn(func, flatten(structure[0]))
# then reapplies the structure[0] to the return value
```

For example:

```py
tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x: x*2, tf.constant((1, 2, 3))) # => (2, 4, 6)
tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x: x*2, (1, (2, 3))) # => (2, (4, 6))
```

#### When `len(structure) > 1`, `func` is applied over the zip of all structure's elements

Conceptually:

```py
tf.map_fn(func, zip(*[flatten(_) _ in structure]))
# then reapplies the structure[0] to the return value 
# (all elements in structure must have the same structure,
#  i.e., structure[0] structureEqualsTo structure[1], etc.,)
```

For example:

```py
tf.nest.map_structure(lambda *x: sum(x), [1, [0]], [2, [4]], [3, [5]]) 
# => [sum([1,2,3]),[sum([0,4,5])]] == [6, [9]]
```